# Get Wireless LAN IPv4 Address Of Device

Tags: ip, ipv4, lan

I want to know the easiest way and I would perfer a single line command that works on most or all Linux distros. I want to get the devices IPv4 address.

The reason why I want to know this is because I use XAMPP and to test my websites out on my phone I like to have my computer and phone connected to the same WiFi network and I connect to my website by my computers IP address.

Comment: use command: `ifconfig`

Answer (score 0):

The traditional command, on Unix, is `ifconfig`.

eg

```
% ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.137  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        ....
```

This command has been deprecated and may not always be installed by default.  The modern command is `ip`.

```
% ip -4 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.0.137/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 18396sec preferred_lft 18396sec
```